# Feed observable data into other observable subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, observable

I'm creating an app and want users to open their active chat. It is powered by Firebase as backend. However, after retrieving data from the first observable subscription which I need to use to feed as a parameter in the second Observable subscription, the second subscription doesn't return any data: it's empty.

In the first subscription I retrieve a unique ChatID. With the second subscription I want to receive all the messages from the Firebase collection with this ChatID.

I already found that it has something to do with the asynchronous style of observables, but I don't know how to nest observables since neither FlatMap nor MergeMap works with my observable.

```
    //First subscription
    this.ActieveGebruikerObservable = this.firebaseService.Gebruiker_lezen(this.ActieveGebruiker.uid);
    this.ActieveGebruikerObservable.subscribe(
      val => this.ActieveGebruikerDetails = val
    );

    //Second subscription
    this.ActieveChatObservable = this.firebaseService.Chat_lezen(this.ActieveGebruiker.uid, this.ActieveGebruikerDetails.ActieveChat);
    this.ActieveChatObservable.subscribe(
      val => this.ActieveChatDetails = val
    );
```

So it seems like `this.ActieveGebruikerDetails.ActieveChat` is empty when fed as paramter into the second subscription. However, when I display it as `{{this.ActieveGebruikerDetails.ActieveChat}}` on the page, it returns the desired value.

I want to retrieve the second subscription data, and not to be it blank data.

Comment: I think a bit of your code got chopped off.
Can you post a bit more of where ActieveGebruiker and ActieveGebruikerDetails.ActieveChat are set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path with looking into `mergeMap` ( `flatMap` == `mergeMap` )

Since you didn't give the name of the first observable, I'll give call it `foo`

```
foo.pipe(
    tap(val => this.ActieveGebruikerDetails = val), // If you still wanted it present on `this`, but not needed
    mergeMap(val => this.firebaseService.Chat_lezen(this.ActieveGebruiker.uid,val.ActieveChat) // map to the firebase observable, using the value from the previous observable, allowing you to access ActieveChat
).subscribe(
  val => this.ActieveChatDetails = val
);
```

Comment: Well that works! Thanks a lot, have been struggling with it for days.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use RxJS operators to connect these observables. Like,

Someservice.switchMap(val => { 
this.ActieveGebruikerDetails = val;
return this.firebaseService.Chat_lezen(this.ActieveGebruiker.uid, this.ActieveGebruikerDetails.ActieveChat);
})
.subscribe(val => this.ActieveChatDetails = val);